# Send email from localhost using symfony1.4 Swiftmailer

Tags: php, symfony-1.4, swiftmailer, orangehrm

I am trying to send email from localhost, but i get this message.

```
 03/14/15 10:28:31,121 [4924] ERROR filter.ExceptionCatcherFilter - Uncaught Exception: exception 'Swift_TransportException' with message 'Connection could not be established with host localhost [No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
#10061]' in C:\wamp\www\erp9282014\symfony\lib\vendor\symfony\lib\vendor\swiftmailer\classes\Swift\Transport\StreamBuffer.php:235
```

My configuration in factory.yml is

```
prod:
  mailer:
    class: sfMailer
    param:
      logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
      charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
      delivery_strategy: realtime
    transport:
      class: Swift_SmtpTransport
      param:
        host:       localhost
        port:       25
        encryption: ~
        username:   myname@gmail.com
        password:   my password
```

and in my action files i use.

```
 $this->getMailer();
    $this->getMailer()->composeAndSend("erp@ahg.af","m@ahg.af"," LIVE","BODY");
```

I am really stuck in here

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I come up with this problem. The problem was with my online server. when i changed my server, and every thing worked find.